# How can we implement 'wait' functions when using @FindBy?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

As I am using Page Object Model, I am using `@FindBy` method, but how can I implement the below statement?

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Logout")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using [`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeSelected-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) as :-

```
@FindBy(linkText = "Logout")
WebElement logOut;

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(logOut));
```

Comment: Where can we use new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(logOut));

Comment: You can use there you want to wait until it's visible and clickable in your code..:)

Comment: I tried but it didn't work..anything has to be done?

Comment: What do you mean didn't work?? Is there any exception??

Comment: No exception, no errors, but didn't click the element.

Comment: So Means Problem is with `.click()` instead of `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`...:)

Comment: @Prabhu You can perform click also using `JavascriptExecutor` as `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", logOut);`..

Answer (score 0):

You can set wait for each page

```
PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, TIMEOUT), this);
```

Answer (score 0):

u can create a method like this:

```
private void waitForVisibility(WebElement element) throws Error{
       new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}
```

than call the method when you needed:

```
waitForVisibility(element);//find by element
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that most of the solutions so far are kind of incomplete because you cannot make use of the whole `static` methods provided by the `ExpectedConditions` class.

A starting note and a bit of additional info:
Examples are for C# cause I don't know the Java syntax by heart, but I'm expecting that it's the same.

- The `[FindsBy]` attribute is getting as parameters 2 values. First is an `Enum` that specifies how to find the element (id, xpath, css selector, etc) and the second, more important one for this example, is the `Using` that receives a constant string. This `const` string is used to specify the actual element `id`, `xpath`, etc.
- Most of the `ExpectedConditions` static methods receive as a parameter a `By` element

Having in mind the above statements, I next went and determined what are the elements on the page that I needed to use an explicit wait and built my code:

```
const string loginButtonXpath = "xpath_here";
[FindsBy(How = How.Xpath, Using=loginButtonXpath)]
private IWebElement LoginButton {get;set;}

private By LoginButtonBy
{
    return By.Xpath(loginButtonXpath);
}
```

Having it set this way, a have the `IWebElement` button that I need to click, I have the `By` locator that I can use in my explicit wait and also I have the method to identify the element on the page only in one place, making as easy as before to maintain my automation solution when any changes occurred.

I'm curious how others handled this without losing the built in explicit wait methods.